# TSQL compare varchar in digit form

Tags: t-sql, comparison

Basically i did some comparison in my tsql as below

```
IF ('500' > '400')
PRINT('NO PROBLEM')
ELSE
PRINT('Error')
```

So, in this situation, the comparison should be no problem

```
IF ('2500' > '400')
    PRINT('NO PROBLEM')
ELSE
    PRINT('Error')
```

However, when the situation above appeared, 'Error' will be print. Basically, the code will do the comparison base on the first character of the strings. Can anyone explain?

**Extra Question**:
If i insist to compare the strings without casting it into *INT* or *DOUBLE*. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare `varchar` values, the comparison is lexicographical i.e. according to alphabetical order. Therefore, if you treat 2 numeric values as strings, they will be compared as strings too. That means you need to convert the strings back to a numeric type if you want to compare by numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to compare numerical values.

However, if you cannot convert to numerical values, then you must 'pad' the smallest varchar number with 0, so it gets to the length of the longest varchar number.

So you end up with something like this:

```
IF ('2500' > '0400')
    PRINT('NO PROBLEM')
ELSE
    PRINT('Error')
```

The specifics of  'padding' zeros can be done in many ways.